# Server connection closed by remote host

Tags: ssh, debian, connection

I have a Debian Squeeze VPS. I have set it up with Apache 2.0 and such. Problem is, now I can't access it anymore through my home Internet connection. When I attempt to access the web server through my browser, it just times out. When I do a `ssh -v` I get:

> OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
>
> debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to (SERVER IP) [(SERVER IP)] port 22.
>
> debug1: Connection established.
>
> debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
>
> debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
>
> debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
>
> debug1: identity file ~/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1

And then it hangs, and finally tells me `Connection closed by (SERVER IP)`.

I have tried to access it through another machine using a different connection, and it works perfectly fine, as it should.

I can *ping* it through my own machine, which is MacBook Pro 13" running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion).

I have checked `/etc/hosts.deny` on my server, and it does not mention anything. How can I resolve this problem?

**UPDATE**

Having restarted my router, my IP address is now a different one, and now I can (probably due to that fact) access my server again. I am however, still curious to know the cause of this.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you have a monitoring tool like [Fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) which blocks an IP address after multiple failed attempts.